# How to display Products By a Category in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to display Categories from a port (http://localhost:5000), my database in MangoDB and it showed up successfully in my app Now when I am trying to display the products for each category separately So it does not work. I tried the same way but the message i receive is "No routes match this location". Can one help me to solve this.

Comment: Please share a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. We can't help with code we can't see.

Comment: Are you trying to answer your own question multiple times or did you mean to update your post with the relavent code and details? Based on the code below the products path should be `"/Products/:categoryId"` instead of `"/Products/ :categoryId"`, remove the space before the category id parameter. Otherwise, the link and routes look fine to me. What exactly is the issue? What isn't working as expected? Just the link not found?

Comment: I just post my code if one can see where it is the problem, this is the first time for me to post here. Actually its a little bit difficult to post the code.

Comment: @Rasha, you need to [edit] your _question_ to add more information. The answers section is only for answers. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

```
{
                    categories.map(category => (
                                                  
                           <Link to ={`/Products/${category._id}`} className="category-link"> 
                         
                            <Card className="card-style" key={category._id}>
                                 <Card.Img className="card-image" variant="top" src={category.image}/>
                             
                                 <Card.Body className="card-body">
                                    <Card.Title className="card-title">{category.name} </Card.Title>
                                 </Card.Body>
                           
                            </Card>
                          
                         </Link>                       
                    )
                    )
                }
```

Comment: Categories component

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to add information to your question (as requested by [a commentor](/posts/comments/130881262)). Please [edit your question](/posts/74129328/edit) instead of posting in the answer field.

Answer (score -1):

**products component:**

```js
let {categoryId} = useParams();
const products_URL =`http://localhost:5000/products/${categoryId}`
```